# How can I create an attribute as "not configurable" from an install script?

Tags: attributes, install-script

When I create a dropdown attribute, Magento is always setting the "Use To Create Configurable Product" as `Yes`.

While in the install script I added in the options array to the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute()` method:

```
"in_configurable" => false
```

This option is still not working.

Sample code to add an attribute from an install script:

```
$options = array(
    'type'                       => 'int',
    'label'                      => 'Color',
    'input'                      => 'select',
    'required'                   => false,
    'user_defined'               => true,
    'searchable'                 => true,
    'filterable'                 => true,
    'comparable'                 => true,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
    'is_configurable'            => false,
);
$this->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'size',
    $options
);
```

After I go into the Admin Panel and view the attribute data, the `is_configurable` attribute is set still set as `Yes`.

Comment: try like this format 'is_configurable' => '0'

Comment: @DRAJI does not work, same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should actually use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()`
instead of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute()`

As you have found out in the code, `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute()` only allows the following options:

> backend
>   type
>   table
>   frontend
>   input
>   label
>   frontend_class
>   source
>   required
>   user_defined
>   default
>   unique
>   note
>   global

Whereas `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()` allows all of the above, plus the following options:

> input_renderer
>   global
>   visible
>   searchable
>   filterable
>   comparable
>   visible_on_front
>   wysiwyg_enabled
>   is_html_allowed_on_front
>   visible_in_advanced_search
>   filterable_in_search
>   used_in_product_listing
>   used_for_sort_by
>   apply_to
>   position
>   **is_configurable**
>   used_for_promo_rules

You can use this class even if you have defined another setup class in your `config.xml`:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

// Create your tables, etc

$catalogInstaller = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$catalogInstaller->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'size', array(
    'type'                       => 'int',
    'label'                      => 'Color',
    'input'                      => 'select',
    'required'                   => false,
    'user_defined'               => true,
    'searchable'                 => true,
    'filterable'                 => true,
    'comparable'                 => true,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
    'is_configurable'            => false,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a small improvement though, you can tell Magento to use the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup` class instead of the EAV one in the `config.xml` file of a module. This way, `$this` would be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`, so you won't have to create a new instance of a resource setup in the update/install script.

Comment: @Dan Indeed, the "normal" way would be to specify `<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>` in the `config.xml` file. I used a different technique because I needed to add product attributes (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()`) as well as order attributes (`Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()`) in the same install script.

Answer (score 5):

If you go through the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute()` method, you can find that the options are getting filtered in the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::_prepareValues()` method.

The `_prepareValues` method only allows the following options to go through:

```
'backend_model', 'backend_type', 'backend_table', 'frontend_model',
'frontend_input', 'frontend_label', 'frontend_class',
'source_model', 'is_required', 'is_user_defined', 'default_value',
'is_unique', 'note', 'is_global'
```

Any option that needs to be set, and is not in previous list, cannot be passed into the `addAttribute` method.

The only exception to those are: `sort_order`, `group`, `user_defined` and `option`. Those are used independently from the `_prepareValues` method.

One way to work around this issue, is to update the attribute after it is created, using the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::updateAttribute()` method.

```
$this->updateAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'size',
    'is_configurable',
    false
)
```